# Handling Session for PHP servlet with multiple PHPs

Tags: php, android, mysql, session, servlets

I am developing a game for android which uses PHP servlets to access a database. They are multiple PHP files. My android application asks the PHP files for data stored in the database.
I'm trying to implement some kind of session control for my PHP servlets.
In the PHP referent to the user login(login.php), I added

```
session_start();
    // set time-out period (in seconds)
    $inactive = 1800;

    // check to see if $_SESSION["timeout"] is set
    if (isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
            // calculate the session's "time to live"
            $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
            if ($sessionTTL > $inactive) {
            session_destroy();
            echo "fazer_login_novamente";
            }
    }   

    $_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $json[]=$row;
    }
```

Right after the user succeeds on logging in. Now, after logging in, the application asks for words stored in the database by connecting to another PHP file. This new php (words.php) checks if the user has already started a session or if it's some king of hijacking through the checkSession PHP function of this link:http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-regenerate-id.php

BUt it seems the user always gets the exception "no session started" when connecting to words.php.

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

EDIT: here's a link to words.php: https://www.dropbox.com/s/23em2h3l3hj1via/login.php?dl=0

EDit: here's a link to login.php: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hp6udivy8whvl8/words.php?dl=0

Comment: Can you post words.php? Make sure `session_start();` is in that script as well.

Comment: I edited the topic with links to the PHPs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, in login.php add a variable like

```
$_SESSION['session_set']=true;
```

And, in words.php, do this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['session_set']) {
    //session set (by login.php)
}
else {
    //session not set (by login.php)
}
```

You have to know that at the start of each php file you have to use **session_start();** to access the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: but session_start() won't reset the session id or something like that? If I put it at the beginning of each of my PHP(like words.php), how will I be able to get check for the id?

Comment: no, session start starts a new session if it doesn't exist, but if a session exists, it will just open the existing one